SearchAnchor suggestion show previous data fetched from API
every thing run great only problem is showing data that previously fetched
for example we search "house" then we search "home". after we search "home" then result of "house" shown . always show previously data .
// event listener
    _searchController.addListener(_onTextChanged);

// api call and fetch
 void _onTextChanged() {
    if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) _debounce?.cancel();
    _debounce = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 1100), () async {
      _searchResponse = await ApiHelpers.postData(
        url: "$apiUrl",
        body: {'search_words': _searchController.text},
        token: token,
        method: 'post',
      );
      
      setState(() {
        _searchResponse = jsonDecode(_searchResponse.response);
        _searchItems =
        List<ListTile>.generate(_searchResponse.length, (int index) {
          final String item = _searchResponse[index]['title'];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(item),
            onTap: () {
            },
          );
        });
      });
    });
  }

Widget code:


SearchAnchor(
builder: (a, b) {
return Text(
"search",
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
);
},
suggestionsBuilder: (a, b) {
return _searchItems.map((item) => ListTile(
title: Text(item.title),
// Assuming item has a title property
onTap: () {
// Handle onTap logic
},
))
.toList();
},
searchController: _searchController,
)


used stream_transform and solved
tnx @pskink
